# Orchard can't access file due to permissions

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, permissions, orchardcms

I recently started an Orchard-CMS website. That's a new CMS which uses ASP.NET MVC 3. http://www.orchardproject.net you can find more info.

It has to be really easy to install a theme. But everytime i try that, i get the error that the dependencies.xml file is not accessable. (Orchard needs the dependencies.xml file, to write the links to new theme's and modules)

My site is running on an IIS7 local machine and i granted all permissions to the ASP.NET user and the NETWORK USER. But i still have permission-problems, any ideas?

Comment: What is the user used by you IIS application pool?

Comment: IUSR, NETWORK SERVICE have all permissions on the root of my website.

Comment: Yes, but are you sure that your app pool is running under NETWORK SERVICE or IUSR?

Comment: apparently it's due to a setting with my webhosting company... they're fixing it, not sure what's the problem. For the moment i granted everyone permissions (all_users)... thx for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By default the IIS 7 application pools run under IUSR account, so you should grant this user the appropriate permissions. From security perspective it's good to create a new, separate account for each application pool and I'd advise you to do so. It'll also give you more fine-grained control.

Also, check whether the permission changes **were correctly propagated to App_Data and App_Data/Dependencies folder and their content**. If not, change permissions for Dependencies folder explicitly. *I've noticed that sometimes they don't get propagated correctly if you change permission at the root level.*